# SelectSingleNode not working with date

Tags: c#, xml

I have below xml file -

```
<ImportFiles>
  <ItemHeader FileTypeId="86" ForecastDate="2018-02-01" Version="1" Name="20180201-116_再生品_調整済発注数-Salvage Committed Send Number-86" Status="1" CreatedByName="Amit Vanzari" CreateDate="2018/02/01 17:09:33" UpdatedByName="Amit Vanzari" UpdateDate="2018/02/01 17:09:33" FileNameEN="Salvage Committed Send Number (Daily)" FileNameJP="再生品 調整済発注数" Description="" /> 
  <ItemHeader FileTypeId="86" ForecastDate="2018-02-02" Version="1" Name="20180202-Salvage Committed Send Number" Status="1" CreatedByName="DivakarBabu Lekala" CreateDate="2018/02/02 16:28:59" UpdatedByName="DivakarBabu Lekala" UpdateDate="2018/02/02 16:28:59" FileNameEN="Salvage Committed Send Number (Daily)" FileNameJP="再生品 調整済発注数" Description="" /> 
  <ItemHeader FileTypeId="86" ForecastDate="2018-02-07" Version="1" Name="20180207-116_ Update Delete -Salvage Committed Send Number-" Status="1" CreatedByName="Amit Vanzari" CreateDate="2018/02/07 17:07:59" UpdatedByName="Amit Vanzari" UpdateDate="2018/02/07 17:07:59" FileNameEN="Salvage Committed Send Number (Daily)" FileNameJP="再生品 調整済発注数" Description="" /> 
 </ImportFiles>
```

I am not able to understand why below code is returning `null`, where as xml file has date - 2018-02-02

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ImportFiles/ItemHeader[@ForecastDate = 2018-02-02]")
```

But it is working -

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ImportFiles/ItemHeader[@Version = 1]")
```

Comment: have you tried `@ForecastDate = '2018-02-02'`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad would you mind posting that as the answer? I've just checked it and that was indeed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a date value there which you might need to pass within single quotes as string like `@ForecastDate = '2018-02-02']` .

So most probably you need to specify it in single quotes like following in your xpath:

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ImportFiles/ItemHeader[@ForecastDate = '2018-02-02']");
```

Hope it works.